# Extracting a substring of a string in Python based on presence of another string

Tags: python, regex, string

`common` is always present regardless of string. Using that information, I'd like to grab the substring that comes just before it, in this case, `"banana"`:

```
string = "apple_orange_banana_common_fruit"
```

In this case, `"fruit"`:

```
string = "fruit_common_apple_banana_orange"
```

How would I go about doing this in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) to extract the substring:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'apple_orange_banana_common_fruit'
>>> re.search(r'([a-zA-Z]+)_common', s).group(1)
'banana'
```

Answer (score 3):

This will return a list of matches:

```
import re
string = "apple_orange_banana_common_fruit"
preceding_word = re.findall("[A-Za-z]+(?=_common)", string)
```

If `common` only occurs once per string, you might be better off using [hwnd's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29738114/2202669).

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
string = "apple_orange_bananna_common_fruit"
preceding_word = re.search('([a-zAZ]+)(?=_common)', string)
print (preceding_word.group(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> string = "fruit_common_apple_banana_orange"
>>> parts = string.split('_')
>>> print parts[parts.index('common') - 1]
fruit

>>> string = "apple_orange_banana_common_fruit"
>>> parts = string.split('_')
>>> print parts[parts.index('common') - 1]
banana
```